# why Can't change the state in the render method. What is the best place to change the state before calling render method

Tags: reactjs, components, state, jsx

I'm trying to make a state change in the `render` method but it shows:

*Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

```
class Test extends Component {
    state = { 
        name:[],

    }



    render() {
        this.setState({name:this.props.data})


        return(
          <div>
              {this.state.name.map(e=>(
                  <h3>{e}</h3>
              ))}
          </div>
      );  
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant do this since `setState` calls render, and render calls `setState` and so on... you will end up with an endless loop.

Comment: yes. I want to know what is the best place to update state before rendering the dom.

Comment: But why would you update the state with the data that is... already in state? :) Usually in React you are using event handlers to update the state.

Comment: what about the props? if there are props which I have to update to local state?

Comment: Is this some pared down example, or are you actually trying to do this? Just render straight from props, i.e. `this.props.data.map(e => <h3>{e}</h3>)`

Comment: @DrewReese Prop having an array. it shows extracting one by one.

Comment: I don't understand that last comment. You can't call `setSate` in the render function. Again, I ask if this is some pared down example because typically storing props in state is an anti-pattern. Can you more clearly explain what you are trying to do and why you are trying it that way?

Comment: simply, I want to run some code lines before the render method. Render method user some data Test component does not have yet. I want to configure that data before render method make his first call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set react state in the render function, but you can in the constructor or most of the component lifecycle functions.

Set some initial state in the constructor

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: props.data,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.name.map(e => (
          <h3>{e}</h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or set state in a lifecycle function

```
class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    name: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ name: this.props.data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.name.map(e => (
          <h3>{e}</h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never set state inside render function as it might create a side effect and it will create an infinite render cycle eventually. React calls render() function every time there is a state change. Do a set state outside render function in the event handler function which gets called based on user interaction with the UI.

Below example is a function based component which chnages the button text when the user clicks the button.

```
const DemoApp = (props) => {
          const [state, setState] = useState(false);

          const handleButtonPress = () => {
          setState(true);
          }

return(
      <Button
          onPress={handleButtonPress}
          title={state ? 'Pressed' : 'click Here'}
          color="#841584"

      />
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a situation in which the state of an object depends upon a prop, which keeps changing. In this case, getDerivedStateFromProps method can be handy. The implementation is given on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp). Here is how the method can be used:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {favoritecolor: "red"};
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {favoritecolor: props.favcol };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>My Favorite Color is {this.state.favoritecolor}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header favcol="yellow"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This implementation has been taken from the link above mentioned. It certainly provides an alternative to changing the state inside render method.